# MySQL: Prevent DROP TABLE and TRUNCATE TABLE on Slaves

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.1

Can someone tell me how to prevent the following commands

```
 DROP TABLE <tbl-name>;
 TRUNCATE TABLE <tbl-name>;
```

from being replicated to slaves?

Comment: Out of curiosity, could you elaborate why you wish to do this?  Generally you want your slave to be 1:1 with your master.

Answer (score 4):

Disable binary logging in your session, drop the table, and enable binary logging.

```
SET sql_log_bin = 0;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ... ;
SET sql_log_bin = 1;
```

This works because if the Slaves do not see the `DROP TABLE` command registered in the Master's binary logs, it cannot run the `DROP TABLE`.

I have recommended using `SET sql_log_bin = 0;` before in my earlier posts

- `Nov 12, 2012` : [Mysql replication and ignore tables](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28551/mysql-replication-and-ignore-tables/28564#28564)
- `Feb 03, 2012` : [Scheduled optimization of tables in MySQL InnoDB](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12201/scheduled-optimization-of-tables-in-mysql-innodb/12205#12205)
- `Jul 11, 2011` : [ALTER TABLE on a large table with an indexed column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3760/alter-table-on-a-large-table-with-an-indexed-column/3767#3767) (This is where I use `SET sql_log_bin = 0;` to directly prevent data from being written to Slaves)

Give it a Try !!!